# Changing annotation image at runtime in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotationview

I am trying to change the image in an annotation view when the user drags it. And I am experimenting gin doing it in Swift. I tried both adding a subview as well changing directly the image but it looks like as soon as the image is set on the annotationView or on the subview it remains unchangeable. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it by removing and adding again the changed imageView as a subview.